# Specifying correct path for XLA Flag in WSL

Tags: linux, tensorflow, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSl for running Tf on my local computer.Even though tf can see my GPU whenever I try to run a code that accesses it, if I use a simple model with only Dense Layer, it gives this error.

```
2023-09-08 11:03:52.223394: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:432] Loaded cuDNN version 8600


2023-09-08 11:03:52.235589: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:543] Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice. This may result in compilation or runtime failures, if the program we try to run uses routines from libdevice.


Searched for CUDA in the following directories:

  /mnt/c/Program

  /usr/local/cuda-11.8

  /usr/local/cuda

  .
You can choose the search directory by setting xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir in HloModule's DebugOptions.  For most apps, setting the environment variable XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/path/to/cuda will work.
2023-09-08 11:03:52.380656: I ./tensorflow/compiler/jit/device_compiler.h:186] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
```

And if I am using a cnn architecture my jupyter notebook crashes without any errors.

As stated in error I tried to set an environment variable for my nvvm/libdevice file  using

export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir='/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8'

I also tried

export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir='C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU/Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8'

I am not sure why I can not see the path after space.Isn't using single quote suppose to handle that?
.I am new in Linux so any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
val_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size=2,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))  

validation_generator =  val_datagen.flow_from_directory(val_dir,
                                                         batch_size=2,
                                                         class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                         target_size = (150, 150))



model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
   
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
   
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'), 
    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  
])


from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=100,
            epochs=15,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            validation_steps=50,
            verbose=2
            )
```

**Update**

I solved problem by making an environment varible  named CUDA_DIR which contains path to file that contains nvvm folder.I can train ANN but notebook still crashes when I try to train a cnn

Comment: Please add an error message as text, not a link to the picture on an external resource.

Comment: Edited accordingly.It looks much clearer now.

Comment: Could you provide the notebook here please ?